# How to create borders like this in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create borders for html div like this
I have spent hours on the internet looking for something like this.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: "...spent hours on the internet looking for something...". Did you actually try anything yourself? I would recommend you _[border triangles](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)_ with _pseudo elements_ in `before` and `after`.

Comment: This could be easily done with clip-path property. Just apply clip-path:polygon with the required coordinates to your div element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path


If you don't want to mess your head around how it works. Here is the tool which will do the work for you.
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/